# How I can put USB Drives in a ComboBox in Powershell GUI

Tags: powershell

How can I display USB Sticks/Drives in a Powershell GUI in a Combobox/Dropdown, so i can choose one. I heard something about WMI, but I couldn't get the USB sticks to show up properly in the dropdown menu.

Comment: The WMI class that you want to interrogate is `Win32_LogicalDisk`. Hard disks appear to have DriveType 3, optical drives (CD/DVD) seem to have DriveType 5, network mappings appear to have DriveType 4, USB thumb drives appear to have DriveType 2.

Comment: `Out-GridView -Outputmode Single/Multiple` might come in handy for selecting the drive? It is not sure how you are building a GUI from your question. 
For getting your USB-devices, you might also use `Get-PnpDevice -Class DiskDrive`?